# Autoresizingmask is not working correct

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, autoresizingmask

I placed a UIView with frame (0, 100, 50, 50) programmatically on the screen and set its autoresizingMask to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin and when I begin rotate the screen the view sticks to the right edge, for some reason. If I set view frame (20, 100, 50, 50) everything works well.

What am I doing wrong?

Sample code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *cell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 50, 50)];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
                            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    [self.view addSubview:cell];
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Before rotation:

```
 --------------------------- 
|                           |
|=====                      |
||   |                      |
|=====                      |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
-----------------------------
|             o             |
 ---------------------------
```

After rotation everything works bad:

```
 ------------------------------------------------
|                                            |   |
|                                       =====|   |
|                                       |   ||   |
|                                       =====|   |
|                                            |   |
|                                            | o |
|                                            |   |
|                                            |   |
|                                            |   |
|                                            |   |
|                                            |   |
 ------------------------------------------------

 --------------------------- 
|                           |
|                      =====|
|                      |   ||
|                      =====|
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
-----------------------------
|             o             |
 ---------------------------
```

If I change

UIView *cell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 50, 50)];

to

UIView *cell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 50, 50)];

Before rotation:

```
 --------------------------- 
|                           |
|   =====                   |
|   |   |                   |
|   =====                   |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
-----------------------------
|             o             |
 ---------------------------
```

After rotation everything works good:

```
 -------------------------------------------------
|                                             |   |
|   =====                                     |   |
|   |   |                                     |   |
|   =====                                     |   |
|                                             |   |
|                                             | o |
|                                             |   |
|                                             |   |
|                                             |   |
|                                             |   |
|                                             |   |
 -------------------------------------------------

 --------------------------- 
|                           |
|   =====                   |
|   |   |                   |
|   =====                   |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
-----------------------------
|             o             |
 ---------------------------
```

Comment: What do you want to happen with your original x=0 frame?

Comment: At least the view has to come back to an initial position when I turn the device back to portrait orientation. And I dont understand why view sticks to right edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
                        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```